# Steps to follow when cassandra node goes down and comes back to rebalance

Tags: cassandra

In 5 node cassandra cluster, 1 node died and we recovered it after few days.

On the recovered node, I ran **nodetool repair** , but it never seems to end as it never returns to command prompt

Data distribution too doesn't seems to change when i run **nodetool status** from other nodes.

In System.log of cassandra, I see the below ERROR

> ERROR [RepairJobTask:7] 2017-03-31 12:16:07,898
>   RepairRunnable.java:261 - Repair session
>   b3b72750-15dd-11e7-b158-5d4916117d35 for range [(-167561
>   1436141724195,-1654146357749205555] Validation failed in /x.x.x.x (IP
>   address of the cassandra node where repair is being executed)

Comment: Nodetool repair never seems to end? are you referring is the nodetool repair got stuck? If so check the Cassandra logs and provide the error you have received in the logs.

Comment: @ShobanSundar Added the ERROR that I found in system.log

Comment: Kill the nodetool repair, restart the node and try nodetool repair -pr, this will repair the primary range of that node.

Comment: @ShobanSundar sure. Will try and let u know. Is there any periodic maintenance activity you recommend to all cassandra nodes in general ?

Comment: Repairs in Cassandra should be run periodically to maintain the data integrity. When we run repair, Cassandra repairs all the nodes, but repair -pr repairs only that particular node. You can optimise the repair so that it runs in less time and consuming low resources. Repair optimisation varies between Cassandra version.